# Difference between QUERY EXPANSION and NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE

Tags: mysql

I'm learning and running some tests with mysql queries for ex:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles
        WHERE MATCH (title,body)
        AGAINST ('$term' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

my question is >> what is the difference in use of the each of the following:

```
 //1// AGAINST ('$term' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)

 //2// AGAINST ('$term' WITH QUERY EXPANSION)

 //3// AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I'm not trying to improve my code, I'm just want to understand the thinking behind it.

Comment: Did you try wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_expansion and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing and in your case sites like https://www.mysqltutorial.org/using-mysql-query-expansion.aspx and https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-language-search.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The characteristics of the 3 types of full-text searches:

- IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
  ... your search term will be treated as natural language (being human language). So no special characters here, except for the " (double quote). All words on your stopword list will be excluded when searching!
- IN BOOLEAN MODE
  ... operators can be added to your search term. This means you can specify extra wishes regarding your search. The stopword list rule also applies of course, meaning they will be excluded from your search.
- WITH QUERY EXPANSION (or IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
  ... is as this last name implies an expansion to IN NATURAL MODE. So it basically is the same as this first mode mentioned above, except for this feature: the most relevant words found with your initial search term are added to your initial search term and the final search is performed. The query returns a broader result with your search term and what might be interesting, if you agree with defining interesting in this way. :)

Comment: thank you, i needed it a very clear explanation and that one is very clear and on point.

Answer (score 1):

IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE: In this mode, the search is performed using a natural language search algorithm. Results are ranked based on relevance, with more relevant results appearing first.

IN BOOLEAN MODE: In this mode, the search query is interpreted as a boolean expression. You can use operators such as + (mandatory), - (prohibitive), and * (wildcard) to control the search. Results are not ranked based on relevance.

WITH QUERY EXPANSION: In this mode, the search is performed in natural language mode, but with automatic query expansion. Query expansion means that the search engine expands the search query to include related terms, in an attempt to improve search results.

IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION: This is a combination of natural language mode and query expansion. The search is performed using natural language algorithms, and results are ranked based on relevance. In addition, the search query is automatically expanded to include related terms.

Answer (score -1):

### Official Documentation

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

> There are three types of full-text searches:
>
> A natural language search interprets the search string as a phrase in
> natural human language (a phrase in free text). There are no special
> operators, with the exception of double quote (") characters. The
> stopword list applies.
>
> Full-text searches are natural language searches if the IN NATURAL
> LANGUAGE MODE modifier is given or if no modifier is given.
>
> A boolean search interprets the search string using the rules of a
> special query language. The string contains the words to search for.
> It can also contain operators that specify requirements such that a
> word must be present or absent in matching rows, or that it should be
> weighted higher or lower than usual. Certain common words (stopwords)
> are omitted from the search index and do not match if present in the
> search string. The IN BOOLEAN MODE modifier specifies a boolean
> search.
>
> A query expansion search is a modification of a natural language
> search. The search string is used to perform a natural language
> search. Then words from the most relevant rows returned by the search
> are added to the search string and the search is done again. The query
> returns the rows from the second search. The IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
> WITH QUERY EXPANSION or WITH QUERY EXPANSION modifier specifies a
> query expansion search. Fo r more information.